# Matplotlib: subplot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, subplot

I have several time series signals (8x8) that I would like to plot using subplot. My data are stored in a matrix called H(x, y, N) where N is the number of points in each signal. I would like to display the 64 signals using subplots.

```
fig  = figure(figsize=(12,8))
time = np.arange(0, Nt, 1)

for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        subplot(8,y+1,x+1)
        plot(time,H[x,y,:])
```

What I get is 8 signals in the first row, 4 in the second one, then 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `subplot` indexing works. From the [docs to `subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot):

> `subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)`
>
> Where nrows and ncols are used to notionally split the figure into `nrows * ncols` sub-axes, and *plot_number* is used to identify the particular subplot that this function is to create within the notional grid. *plot_number* starts at 1, increments across rows first and has a maximum of `nrows * ncols`.

So, you want to have `nrows=8`, `ncols=8` and then a `plot_number` in the range 1-64, so something like:

```
nrows,ncols = 8,8
for y in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        plot_number = 8*y + x + 1
        subplot(nrows,ncols,plot_number)
        plot(time,H[x,y,:])
        
        # Remove tick labels if not on the bottom/left of the grid
        if y<7: gca().set_xticklabels([])
        if x>0: gca().set_yticklabels([])
```

To remove tick labels, use `gca()` to get the current axes, and the set the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` to an empty list: `[]`

Comment: I looked for an example online, I guess I really didn't understand how it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know how to remove the values along the axis because I have so many plots that I cannot see anything anymore?

Comment: sure, you need to remove the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`. Try setting them to an empty list for the subplots you want to remove tick labels on. See my edit for a suggestion